# Query issue, no error but it doesn't show anything

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Query issue, it works and gives no error message but it doesn't show what i want it to.
I am trying to list all of the boats that are handled by staff who work in a branch at 21 Harbour Road, Portsmouth

Here is my query sql code:-

```
SELECT boatId, address, city, postcode, type, rooms, price
FROM BoatsForRent
WHERE staffId IN (SELECT staffId
              FROM Staff
              WHERE branchId = (SELECT branchId
                        FROM Branch
                        WHERE address= '21 Harbour Road'))
```

All help appreciated :)

Comment: Try to execute your Query breaking down.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is ok, it for sure is a logic problem. Try to run each subselect starting from the most nested to get what is returning. If you need further help I suggest using SQL fiddler, create example data, try it out and call again.
http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your

WHERE branchID = ( select....

to

WHERE branchID IN ( select....

The equality test is typically between two columns.  You are trying to apply equality from one column to a SELECT statement... The IN is correct where you are testing for qualified staff.

Additionally, this could be written with JOINs such as

```
SELECT 
      bfr.boatId, 
      bfr.address, 
      bfr.city, 
      bfr.postcode, 
      bfr.type, 
      bfr.rooms, 
      bfr.price
   FROM 
      BoatsForRent bfr
         JOIN staff s
            on bfr.staffID = s.staffID
            JOIN Branch b
               on s.branchID = b.branchID
              AND b.address LIKE '21 Harbour Road%'
```

COMMENT FEEDBACK...

Since the above wasn't working, build the query in reverse... ONE STEP AT A TIME, and apply for any future queries.  Break them into smaller pieces until you find the culprit of missing / mismatched elements.

```
select
      b.branchID
   from
      Branch b
   where
      b.address LIKE '21 Harbour Road%'
```

If that fails, was it a type-o, or should it have been "Rd" vs "Road", spelling, spacing, upper/lower case?  One THAT is resolved, now check for staff at that office

```
select
      b.branchID,
      s.staffID
   from
      Branch b
         JOIN staff s
            on b.branchID = s.branchID
   where
      b.address LIKE '21 Harbour Road%'
```

If this return no records, then there are no staff workers as listed associated with the branch in question.   It won't obviously return records of boats for rent if nobody listed at the branch.  Now, add the boats for rent...

```
select
      b.branchID,
      s.staffID,
      bfr.boatId, 
      bfr.address, 
      bfr.city, 
      bfr.postcode, 
      bfr.type, 
      bfr.rooms, 
      bfr.price
   from
      Branch b
         JOIN staff s
            on b.branchID = s.branchID
            JOIN BoatsForRent bfr
               on s.staffID = bfr.staffID
   where
      b.address LIKE '21 Harbour Road%'
```

If this STILL fails, then remove the WHERE clause and get ALL boats for rent, then just add an

```
ORDER BY b.address
```

And see where ALL the boats are associated with...  Sometimes being overloaded when young in SQL can cause problems... Slow steps are sometimes needed.

**COMMENT FEEDBACK.**

By looking at your revised post, I'm now seeing your address include ", Portsmouth", so your query would be failing as

```
address = '21 Harbour Road'
```

is not the same as

```
address = '21 Harbour Road, Portsmouth'
```

I have changed to

```
address LIKE '21 Harbour Road%'
```

The '%' is like a wild-card, so as long as the address STARTS with '21 Harbour Road' will qualify.

Comment: Still doesn't return anything. Thanks though

Comment: @user3072131, see revised answer.

Comment: @user3072131, see my revised answer... EQUALITY vs LIKE since you now have ", Portsmouth" as part of the location.

Comment: awesome thanks for all your help, i still get an error though: MySQL returned an empty result set.

I have it in my data but for some reason its not working. But its fine i'm just gonna leave this query. Thanks for everything :D